# Problem with boxes and paragraphs

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, ulem

I am trying to create a form for my company. I am new to Latex and based on some tutorials i was able to get to a certain point. But as you can see

1. The `fbox` is starting from a different margin
2. I am trying to get the paragraph to move up close to the first table.
3. The table that starts with an arrow seems to start before the margin, how do i align them
4. I am trying to have the underline of "unit holder information" to match the bottom line of the `fbox` and extend it to the rest of the line. 4.

Any help on these would be appreciated.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.45cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{
\fbox{\phantom{\rule{.7ex}{.7ex}}}\hspace{1pt}\underline{\textbf{#1}\hfill}\tabularnewline
} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref,wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{nscenter}
 \textbf{\Large ABC COMPANY Transaction Form}{\footnotesize (For existing     unit holders only)}
\end{nscenter}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{4.2cm}|>{\centering}p{4.0cm}|>{\centering}p{3.9cm}|>{\centering}p{3.1cm}|>{\centering}p{3.0cm}|}
\hline 
Broker ARN & Sub Broker/Branch Code & Sub-Broker ARN & EUIN &             Date\tabularnewline
\hline 
{\textbf{\large ABC 12345}} &  &{\textbf{\normalsize A012344}} &      &\underline{${}$\hspace{0.6cm}}/\underline{${}$\hspace{0.6cm}}/\underline{${}$\hspace{1.0cm}} \tabularnewline[1.0pt]
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\
\normalsize
\fboxrule=1pt \fbox{\phantom{\rule{2.7ex}{2.7ex}}} \fbox{\parskip=0pt\parbox[t]{0.90\textwidth}{\raggedright{}{\tiny I/We hereby     confirm that the EUIN box has been intentionally left blank by me/us as this is     an “execution-only” transaction without any interaction or advice by the     employee/relationship manager/sales person of the above distributor or     notwithstanding the advice of in-appropriateness, if any, provided by the     employee/relationship manager/sales person of the distributor and the     distributor has not charged any advisory fees on this transaction.\par}}}\\
\hspace{0.5cm}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{p{2.3cm}|p{4.4cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{3.7cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{4.5cm}}
\hline
{\textbf{\huge\hspace{4pt}\ding{220}}}\parbox[t]    {0.85\textwidth}{Sole/First\\ unit Holder}& &\parbox[t]{0.85\textwidth}{Second     \\unit Holder}& &\parbox[t]{0.85\textwidth}{Third\\ unit holder}&     \tabularnewline
\hline  
\end{tabular}\\\\
\normalsize
\underline{\textbf{ABC Company Transfer}}\\
\myheading{Unit Holder Information}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. It is great that you've provided a working example. That's helpful but it is not at all *Minimal*. Try to reduce the code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. If Verdana isn't necessary, for example, drop it. (That will increase the number of people who can compile your code and potentially help - not everyone has Verdana.) EDIT: Also, please check your code compiles before posting. This does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, using the `makecell`package for a better vertical spacing and `hhline` to make the square. No need for `nscenter` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=0.45cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref,wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\parindent = 0pt
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
\newlength{\sqside}
\setlength{\sqside}{2.85ex }

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{4.2cm}|>{\centering}p{4.0cm}| >{\centering}p{3.9cm}| >{\centering}p{3.1cm}| >{\centering}p{3.0cm}|}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{{\bfseries\Large ABC COMPANY Transaction Form} (For existing unit holders only)}\\[2ex]
\hline
\makecell*{Broker ARN} & Sub Broker/Branch Code & Sub-Broker ARN & EUIN & Date\tabularnewline
\hline%
\makecell*{\bfseries\large ABC 12345} & &{\bfseries\normalsize A012344} & & \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\underline{${}$\hspace{0.6cm}} / \underline{${}$\hspace{0.6cm}} / \underline{${}$\hspace{1.0cm}}}\tabularnewline[1.0pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr 18.2cm + 10\tabcolsep + 6\arrayrulewidth\relax}{|l||>{\tiny}X|}
\hhline{|-||-|}
\makebox[\sqside][c]{} & I/We hereby confirm that the EUIN box has been intentionally left blank by me/us as this is an “execution-only” transaction without any interaction or advice by the employee/relationship manager/sales person of the above distributor or notwithstanding the advice of in-appropriateness, if any, provided by the employee/relationship manager/sales person of the distributor and the distributor has not charged any advisory fees on this transaction. \\
\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabularx}\\[10pt]
\hspace{0.5cm}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr 18.2cm + 10\tabcolsep + 6\arrayrulewidth\relax}{ll|X|l|X|l|X}
\hline
\makecell{\textbf{\huge\ding{220}}} & \makecell*{Sole/First\\ unit Holder}& &\makecell{Second \\unit Holder}& &\makecell{Third\\ unit Holder}& \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\mbox{}\\[6ex]
{\normalsize\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|l|l@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\underline{\normalsize\bfseries ABC Company Transfer}}\\[6pt]
\cline{1-1}
\makebox[0.92ex][c]{}& Unit Holder Information \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @tayirvadai: I propose a solution with better alignment on both sides and a simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

Tabulars have some spacing around them. The easiest way to keep stuff aligned is to keep it in the tabular. In this case, though, you need different column specifications. So it would be best to use tabulars of uniform width. You can use `tabular*` for this as I do for one of the tabulars, but I also used the `tabularx` package. This requires at least one column to be 'stretchy' as it adjusts the column widths rather than the intercolumn spacing. I've also used `array` which allows me some more options for specifying columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.45cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}% tabularx would load array anyway but include for transparency
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}% this defines a new column type which will centre the contents horizontally and vertically in a parbox of specified width
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref,wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{nscenter}
 \textbf{\Large ABC COMPANY Transaction Form\footnotesize (For existing unit holders only)}
\end{nscenter}
{\centering% we don't want stray spaces messing up the alignment so comment the ends of lines
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}%
\footnotesize%
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{.975\textwidth}{|C{4.2cm}|C{4.0cm}|C{3.9cm}|C{3.1cm}|>{\centering}X|}% a tabular of width .975\textwidth - at least one column must be X so that tabularx can adjust it to match the request width. This won't get centred automatically, so centre it explicitly
  \hline
  Broker ARN & Sub Broker/Branch Code & Sub-Broker ARN & EUIN & Date\tabularnewline
  \hline
  \textbf{\large ABC 12345} &  & \textbf{\normalsize A012344} & &\underline{\hspace{0.6cm}}/\underline{\hspace{0.6cm}}/\underline{\hspace{1.0cm}}\tabularnewline[1.0pt]
  \hline
\end{tabularx}\\
\normalsize%
\fboxrule=1pt%
\begin{tabularx}{.975\textwidth}{l>{\centering}X}% just for alignment - one column which obviously has to be X
    \fbox{\phantom{\rule{2.7ex}{2.7ex}}} &
    \fbox{\parskip=0pt\parbox[b]{0.90\textwidth}{\raggedright\tiny I/We hereby confirm that the EUIN box has been intentionally left blank by me/us as this is an “execution-only” transaction without any interaction or advice by the employee/relationship manager/sales person of the above distributor or notwithstanding the advice of in-appropriateness, if any, provided by the employee/relationship manager/sales person of the distributor and the distributor has not charged any advisory fees on this transaction.}}\tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}\\
\scriptsize%
\begin{tabular*}{.975\textwidth}{p{2.3cm}|p{4.4cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{3.7cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{4.5cm}}% a tabular* so no need for X here
  \hline
  \raisebox{-8pt}[-4pt][0pt]{\textbf{\huge\hspace{4pt}\ding{220}}}\parbox[t]{0.85\textwidth}{Sole/First\\unit Holder}& &\parbox[t]{0.85\textwidth}{Second\\unit Holder}& &\parbox[t]{0.85\textwidth}{Third\\unit holder}& \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\medskip\\
\normalsize%
\begin{tabularx}{.975\textwidth}{X}% another tabular just for alignment
  \underline{\textbf{ABC Company Transfer}}\tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}\\
\begin{tabularx}{.975\textwidth}{m{1.25em}>{\bfseries}X}% a very narrow column, vertically centred for the box followed by the stretchy column
  \fbox{\phantom{\rule{.7ex}{.7ex}}} & Unit Holder Information
  \tabularnewline\cline{2-2}% using cline to underline ensures the line runs the full width
\end{tabularx}\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Form with tabularx and tabular*]

Comment: Thanks @cft appreciate your help. Once last question though. As you can see the box before the declaration is a little bit inside, is there a way to properly align that as well?

Comment: @tayirvadai See my updated answer. Is that what you meant? If you don't want the declaration paragraph centred, just change `\centering` for the second column for that tabular. (That is, you need the `X` but you can change the `\centering`.) Using `\hfill` will align the box right but I think this leaves too much of a gap between the checkbox on the left and the textbox on the right. (You could always slightly increase the width of the `\parbox` of course.) Or to left align it, just remove `>{\centering}` altogether.

Comment: @tayirvadai I think you meant to comment on Bernard's answer but you've actually thanked Bernard for mine ;).

Comment: Sorry @cfr. I am new in using the interface.